# Namespaces that prepend the current namespace

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces

I have a class wrapper, class `car`, that lives in the namespace of `Automobile`. Then I have class `tire` that lives in the namespace of `Automobile\Wheels`. In the tire class, I want to access a static variable from the car class, but the only way to do that is to reference the complete namespace\class.

```
<?php

namespace Automobile;

class Car {
    public static $Axle;

    public function __construct() {
        static::$Axle = new Axle();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Automobile\Wheels;

class Tire {
    public $size;
    public function __construct($size = 16) {
        $this->size = $size;

        \Automobile\Car::$Axle->add_wheel($this);
    }
}
```

My questions are: is it an okay practice to reference classes like this? Are there any ways to reference the class without including the complete and absolute namespace for the class?

Comment: You can add a use statement to the top of the file `use Automobile\Car;` which will then let you use `Car` as a class in the same namespace in that file. Beware of collisions, which you can avoid with aliasing `use Automobile\Car as CarAliasHere;`. Which will then allow you to use `CarAliasHere` in that file.

Comment: That works. I tried `use Autmobile;` but adding the class name to the end of that was what did it. Setting an alias helps a bunch too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's really no good or bad way to do it, although people might be quite opinionated about it (the same with using spaces or tabs for indents, but let's not go down that road ;) ). As long as they're properly referenced it's okay to use fully qualified class names.

You might want to use the `use` keywords to 'import' external classes, which improves the readability in my opinion:

```
<?php
namespace Automobile\Wheels;

use Automobile\Car;

class Tire {
    public $size;
    public function __construct($size = 16) {
        $this->size = $size;

        Car::$Axle->add_wheel($this);
    }
}
```

You might want to reference the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), as it is quite concise about the subject and gives good insight in how to use namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, use `use` for the full namespaced class (e.g., `use Automobile\Car;`). From there, you can use the shortened class reference (e.g., `Car`) throughout the rest of the file.

As an aside, it's best practice to avoid statically invoking properties and method if at all possible. It's generally considered best practice to inject your dependencies as it decouples your code and allows for swapping out of pieces of your application using interfaces.

I would do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Automobile;

class Car {
    /** @var Axle */
    public $axle;

    public function __construct(Axle $axle) {
        $this->axle = $axle;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Automobile\Wheels;

use Automobile\Car;

class Tire {

    public $size;

    public function __construct(Car $car, $size = 16) {
        $this->size = $size;
        $car->axle->add_wheel($this);
    }
}
```